# Android Zxing - What is the framing rectangle for?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I know you should put the codes there, but why it's needed in the first place? I mean, why not using the whole screen (I suppose there's a reason and I need it to justify the behavior to my client).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main reasons are:

1. It helps users to align the code, to reduce rotation.
2. An important one: most devices can't focus anything from too close. In order to fit the code inside the viewfinder, user needs to leave some space between the code and the device. This space allows camera to focus.

However, I have modified ZXing's code to make it scan with the whole screen and it's working great! But I still draw the viewfinder for the 2 reasons mentioned above.